# URL Schema for launching GDrive/Docs from custom iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, url-scheme

I am trying GDrive SDK integration for my prototype iOS app. I fetch all the files stored in GDrive to my app through GDrive SDK API call. I want to open the file directly into GDrive iOS app when I try to open file using  'alternatelink' provided for each file in GDrive.

**GTLDriveFile class**

`// A link for opening the file in using a relevant Google editor or viewer.
@property (copy) NSString *alternateLink;`

```
//Sample code
GTLDriveFile *file = ....;
// file.alternateLink is used to launch the app to safari
// To open link in iOS GDrive app we need to add schema 'googledrive://'
NSString *urlString = [@"googledrive://" stringByAppendingString:file.alternateLink];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

I just wanted to confirm, Is this the right way to launch the GDrive app or is there any alternate full proof solution to do that.

**Update**: I wanted to confirm Google won't change the schema URL from **googledrive://** to something else to launch so that in future my app will stop launching GDrive app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, URL Schemes are the only way to communicate with other apps.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html

However, these URL Schemes can be defined by the Developer, therefore Google can change the Scheme with each App update. Therefore, nobody can confirm that Google won't change the Scheme.

Comment: Yes. I just wanted confirmation from the google guys since they have mentioned that they will be looking for issues like these related to GoogleDriveSdk

Answer (score 0):

This is what got the answer in Developer portal

https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20API%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=3917